# django - override User model entries

Tags: django

Is it possible to override the name of both `is_superuser` and `is_staff` to custom values?

Nothing I'm seeing would make it possible I'm guessing the alternative would be to do an `AbstractUser` and then make new values for what is required like `is_admin` and then reference that boolean instead and hide the `is_staff` as an example from all forms?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user) recommends that if you are unhappy with the built-in User model to extend AbstractUser and implement your own custom User class. You will need to add additional values (AUTH_USER_MODEL in Django 1.10) in your settings file to tell Django to use the new model.

Comment: @Neelik - actually it's AbstractBaseUser and I'm working on that now.

Comment: You are correct. Thank you for correcting the class name.

Comment: Please feel free to add as the answer so I can close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user) recommends that if you are unhappy with the built-in User model to extend AbstractBaseUser and implement your own custom User class.

You will need to add additional values (AUTH_USER_MODEL in Django 1.10) in your settings file to tell Django to use the new model.